# Azure - npm not a recognized command

Tags: azure, npm

I am getting the following bizarre error on Azure.

When I run Kudu it reports the proper version of npm and when I run it from the CMD it runs npm fine.

What the heck is going on?  Is this some sort of a PATH issue or something?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
>   occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
>   Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command,

[image: npm issues]

**Edit** To clarify further.

npm runs in the Kudu command like, so does node.  The versions are correct, and the location in the PATH is also correct.

[image]

Comment: it does not have anything to do with Azure, is this happening for an angular/front end app?

Comment: This is only occuring on Azure, but yes it's an Angular 7 / .Net Core 2.0 application that works fine on my development machine.   This error only occured after I had to upgrade node/npm from the ancient defaults that Azure starts with up to the versions shown there.  Now I can run npm from the Azure command line, but the app fails saying it can't find it.  I even did an npm install, worked fine.  But app fails with that error.

Comment: Fails at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)`

Comment: Run npm audit fix in powershell

Comment: Seems unrelated to not being able to find npm but I got this among a few others: npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@7.0.0 (sha512-4fkohfGyG1BEpeYenOartuJmduyZ/R3XQx46hDDiR/9A8/Go4qLGkgr9Bd/JL/gPIR1XAHH9D5ii2sh+28ZEmA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@3.1.3 (sha512-+81MUSyX+BaSo+u2RbozuQk/UWx6hfG0a5gHu4ANEM4sU96XbuIyAB+rWBW1u70c6a5QuZfuYICn3s2UjuHUpA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

Answer (score 1):

### You can follow the following steps:

- Install/Re-install node.
- Shutdown your PC for 5 minutes.
- Search *environment variables* from start menu's search box.
- Click it then go to *Environment Variables*
- Click **PATH**
- Click **Edit**
- Click **New** and try to *copy* and *paste* your path for '*bin*' folder [find where you installed the node] for example according to my machine '`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`'

#### If you got any error. try the another step:

- Click **New**, then browse for the '*bin*' folder